# How to disable the maximizing option in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I was creating a JavaFX program. I have used .fxml codes to design the page but there is a problem, whenever I run the program it works fine with the default height and width but when I maximize that result, the buttons and other contents remain at their original position of default height and width. They didn't adjust with the height and width. Because it is an mp3 player and can perform some other minor functions, so I want that its size should not be expandable (it can not be maximized). This will solve my problem too.

.fxml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<GridPane alignment="top_left" hgap="10" prefHeight="475.0" prefWidth="800.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Label prefHeight="49.0" prefWidth="800.0" text="Spotify Downloader Music Player">
         <font>
            <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="24.0" />
         </font>
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="10.0" />
         </GridPane.margin></Label>
      <GridPane GridPane.rowIndex="1">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="392.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="253.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="551.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="391.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="551.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="217.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="275.0" text="Home">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="257.0" text="Playlist" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="257.0" text="Settings" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="257.0" text="About" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Label prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="253.0" text="Music name" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <TextField prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="543.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </TextField>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Search" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

How to disable the maximizing option in JavaFX?

How to change the contents position with size expansion?

Comment: Your code needs to be a part of your question.  If that project ever goes away or is modified, your question will have no value to future readers.  That said, I’m guessing you used AnchorPanes and absolute coordinates for placing your child nodes;  try replacing all use of Panes and AnchorPanes with the other layout choices.

Comment: You’re asking the wrong question.  Forcing the sizes of your window and its components in terms of pixels will make them ugly and/or unusable for users on other computers, who have different screens and different fonts.  This is why layouts exist:  to correctly and gracefully handle all of that.  Once you use layouts properly, you won’t have to concern yourself with the user resizing or maximizing the window.

Comment: On Windows, at least, calling `stage.setResizable(false)` disables the maximize button.

Comment: @Slaw In Linux and mac, is there any other code?

Comment: I don't have a Linux or Mac to test with. Have you tried `setResizable` on those two platforms?

Comment: don't __shout__ at somebody who tries to help you! Particularly not, if s/he is right on spot as @VGR - you have a problem with your layout, disabling resize will doctor the symptoms but will not fix the underlying issue: learn about layouts and how to use them

Comment: @Slaw `stage.setResizable(false)` also works in Linux. Please write this command in the answer section, your command is more correct. :)

Comment: @kleopatra May be my comment sounds like I'm shouting I'm sorry for that but the question was different. I was asking for somethig else. VGR comment is the alternative for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the [`resizable` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#resizableProperty) of `Stage` to `false` it disables the maximize button while leaving alone the minimize button.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Create Scene and add it to primaryStage
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

This only stops the user from resizing the `Stage` but doesn't stop you (the developer) from resizing the `Stage` programmatically.

> Defines whether the Stage is resizable or not by the user.
>   Programatically you may still change the size of the Stage. This is a
>   hint which allows the implementation to optionally make the Stage
>   resizable by the user.

The Javadoc indicates this is only a hint to the implementation. I could only test this on a Windows 10 machine, however, but you mention in the question comments it works on a Linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a utility window which will remove the maximize and minimize options from the toolbar.

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
```

Or you could set a max height and width on the stage.  For example:

```
stage.setMaxHeight(400.0);
stage.setMaxWidth(600.0);
```

However users may be confused if they have the option to maximize, but the window only goes to a specific height.

Comment: `stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);` also disable minimize option which is not needed. Is there any other way to disable only maximize option?

Comment: technically correct (modulo some visual issues with such a window, there was a question a couple of days ago that I don't find right now) but will do nothing to solve OPs real problem which is an incorrect layout ;)